# Android concertina/accordian/folding animation

Tags: android, animation

I'm trying to create an interactive accordian/concertina/folding animation so that a view folds/unfolds on itself when interacted with - in the same way [flipboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=flipboard.app&referrer=utm_source=flipweb&utm_medium=web_button&utm_term=android&utm_campaign=download_button_android) folds the view, but both sides fold

The way I thought I could do it was to override the onDraw method, somehow duplicate the canvas or the information on the canvas, then draw the first half of the canvas rotated one way, then draw the other half of the canvas rotated the other way so that they meet in the middle, however I can't seem to grab the information from the canvas! Is it possible to grab a bitmap/snapshot from a canvas?

The only other way I think it's possible to achieve this kind of animation is with OpenGL.

Any help are greatly appreciated.

EDIT heres a good example of what i want to achieve http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2008/03/28/arts/20080330_FOLD_IN_FEATURE.html

Comment: it's an old post, but have you found out how to do? I'm interested in this too !

Comment: The closest thing to helping I could find was this open source flip board like animation framework for android: https://github.com/openaphid/android-flip

Comment: i've seen this library too, thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this archive to acheive fold animation

code: http://developer.android.com/shareables/devbytes/FoldingLayout.zip

modifies it to make it work for lower version up till API level11