# Canvas animate "closing the book"

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas, android-animation

First of all I never used canvas transformations before. But here is that I have to do:

say I have a canvas that holds an image. I need to transform it like this

[image: original image] to this [image]

I'm able to rotate the canvas like following:

[image] and [image]

Here is the code I'm using for the left one:

```
public void transformCanvas(Canvas canvas, float percentOpen) {
    Camera camera = new Camera();
    canvas.translate(0, canvas.getHeight()/2);
    camera.translate(0, 0, Math.abs(90 * percentOpen - 90));
    camera.rotateY(Math.abs(90 * percentOpen - 90));
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    camera.getMatrix(matrix);
    canvas.concat(matrix);
    canvas.translate(0, -canvas.getHeight()/2);
}
```

`percentOpen` holds the value from `0` to `1` so that when `percentOpen` decreases the canvas rotates till it becomes invisible and when `percentOpen` increases the canvas returns to its original state.

I'm able to animate both left and right variants, I just cannot figure out how should I divide the canvas into two parts (or even should I divide it somehow?) to animate the left and right parts independently.

I tried taking the bitmap of the view, divide it into two `Bitmap`s and rotate them independently but this was very slow. 
I'd be very glad for any help.

**How can I rotate the left and right sides independently?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this custom Animation:

```
class V extends View implements OnClickListener {

    private A animation;
    private Paint paint0;
    private Paint paint1;
    private RectF rect;
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    public V(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint0 = new Paint();
        paint0.setColor(0xffaa0000);
        paint1 = new Paint();
        paint1.setColor(0xffffffff);
        rect = new RectF();
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick ");
        animation = new A(getWidth(), getHeight());
        startAnimation(animation);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int w = getWidth();
        int h = getHeight();
        if (animation != null && animation.hasStarted() && !animation.hasEnded()) {
            canvas.save();
            canvas.clipRect(0, 0, w / 2, h, Op.REPLACE);
            canvas.concat(animation.leftMatrix);
            drawStuff(canvas, w, h);
            canvas.restore();

            canvas.save();
            canvas.clipRect(w / 2, 0, w, h, Op.REPLACE);
            canvas.concat(animation.rightMatrix);
            drawStuff(canvas, w, h);
            canvas.restore();
        } else {
            drawStuff(canvas, w, h);
        }
    }

    public void drawStuff(Canvas canvas, int w, int h) {
        int s = Math.min(w, h);
        rect.set(0, 0, s, s);
        rect.offset((w - s) / 2, (h - s) / 2);
        canvas.drawRect(rect, paint0);

        rect.left += 64;
        rect.top += 64;
        canvas.drawOval(rect, paint1);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect.left, rect.top, null);
    }

    class A extends Animation {
        private Camera camera;
        private int w2;
        private int h2;
        public Matrix leftMatrix;
        public Matrix rightMatrix;

        public A(int w, int h) {
            camera = new Camera();
            leftMatrix = new Matrix();
            rightMatrix = new Matrix();
            w2 = w / 2;
            h2 = h / 2;
            setDuration(2000);
        }

        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            camera.save();
            float angle = 80 * interpolatedTime;

            camera.rotateY(angle);
            camera.getMatrix(leftMatrix);
            leftMatrix.preTranslate(-w2, -h2);
            leftMatrix.postTranslate(w2, h2);

            camera.rotateY(-2 * angle);
            camera.getMatrix(rightMatrix);
            rightMatrix.preTranslate(-w2, -h2);
            rightMatrix.postTranslate(w2, h2);

            camera.restore();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, as you put effort in this I'll mark this as accepted. However, I found what I was looking for. The effect I wanted to achieve is called `folding` and is answered here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12798103/android-concertina-accordian-folding-animation